# Touch application with PIC16F183x possible?

Tags: pic, microchip

I could'nt find any information about touch applications in the datasheet from the PIC16F183x controller. Ist this controller fine for touch applications? It's in a list with supported devices for the mtouch library.

Comment: Touch buttons? Touch screen? Touch sliders? If cost is not an issue also explore fixed function touch controllers..like MBR3xxx from cypress for example.. I would spend a lil more and make the system robust  unless it is only for experiments

Comment: 1...3 Buttons. I will check the MBR3. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the part has no dedicated capacitive touch hardware, the ADC inputs can be used for capacitive touch.  For more noise-immune and robust capacitive touch applications, Microchip (and other suppliers) make dedicated hardware (recommended).  To use the ADC input, see http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/AppNotes/01298A.pdf .